# NHibernate.Linq to Criteria API translation help needed

Tags: nhibernate

I'm not sure how to add paging to this:

```
Session.Linq<Article>()
  .Where(art => art.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == tag)).ToList().
```

So i decided to use Criteria API.

```
var rowCount = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Article))
  .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount()).FutureValue<Int32>();

var res = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Article))
  .Add(/* any help with this? :) */)
  .SetFirstResult(page * pageSize)
  .SetMaxResults(pageSize)    
  .AddOrder(new Order("DatePublish", true))
  .Future<Article>();

totalCount = rowCount.Value;
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In link to do paging you use the commands `Skip` and `Take`.

Your scenario:

```
Session.Linq<Article>()
  .Where(art => art.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == tag))
  .Skip(2*20).Take(20)
  .ToList();

int totalCount = Session.Linq<Article>()
                     .Where(art => art.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == tag))
                     .Count();
```

Comment: Yeah, but how to retrieve total count? And how to do that in same database request? I don't want to retrieve thousands of articles in memory.

Comment: I have not done a tonne of this but I pretty sure in most cases you just call the count method. Depending on what LINQ provider you are using there might be a better way to get the count after a query has executed. The NHibernate LINQ Provider may have a better way to do this I just thought I would provide the bare minimum LINQ.

Comment: I'm quite sure this will result in 2 database hits. Will be surprised if it won't. Will try and post profiler log. :)

Comment: Ya I fairly certain this will hit the database twice.

Comment: Yap... 2 selects (i did try to leave first expression result as IQueryable until 2nd select returns count). At the moment - i don't care much (facing deadlines), but it's not the right answer to question (actually - knew this myself). :)